# convert from sendump to mixture_weights in pocketsphinx

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am doing adaptaion of my custom acoustic model. I refered this [link](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt)
 , but i need  `mixture_weights`
 file for adaptation, when i am going to convert `sendump` file to `mixture_weights` file by using command

```
   /python sphinxtrain\python\cmusphinx\sendump.py  /sendump  /mixture_weights
```

it gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sphinxtrain\python\cmusphinx\sendump.py", line 82, in <module>
    s3mixw.open(sys.argv[2], 'wb').writeall(Sendump(sys.argv[1]).mixw())
  File "sphinxtrain\python\cmusphinx\sendump.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.load(filename)
  File "sphinxtrain\python\cmusphinx\sendump.py", line 58, in load
    cluster_count = (int)(header.split()[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'centroids'
```

Comment: i installed numpy and scipy using commands    'pip install numpy' and 'pip install scipy' respectvely ,but now it gives                                     ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'centroids'

Answer (score 0):

Not every `sendump` format can be convered. Sometimes you need to find old `mixture_weights` or you have to retrain the model from scratch.